# Force image to the bottom of the page if too short

Tags: javascript, css

I have an odd requirement for a mobile web page. The page will only be viewed on mobile (Android 4.4 and up and iOS 7 and up).

The page has a single image, nothing else. The image is set to 100% for the width. If the image is too small to fill the screen we want to drop it to the bottom of the page (the image has something special that needs to be seen at the bottom of the page). The quick fix we have is to do:

```
img { position: absolute; bottom:0 }
```

This works fine if the image is too small, however if you flip the phone into landscape you cannot scroll up the top of the image.

Is there a way to make it so that the image is only forced to the bottom if it is too short to fill the screen/taller than the screen?

A CSS only solution is preferred, but JS is ok too.

Comment: not sure I understand what you really need, but maybe media queries help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I'm a bit astound someone with this much rep hasn't been able to post a clear question... why wouldn't you be able to scroll to the top? And what on earth does this mean : '*only forced to the bottom if it is too short to fill the screen/taller than the screen?*'.

Comment: Sorry, I think the question is clear, no need to be insulting. Let's assume the image is 500x700 and the screen is 500x800 (for arguments sake). At the moment the image has 100 pixels below it, I want the image to have 100 pixels above it. However if the screen is 500x600 I want it at the top so they can scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Don't see an insult there and had no intention that way, I was obviously not the only one not getting it. I think media queries would indeed be the way to go (using some aspect ratio as well).

Comment: "I'm a bit astound someone with this much rep hasn't been able to post a clear question"

Comment: That just means I'm surprised (has a typo). It's really up to you to experience it as an insult, I was simply saying what I had concluded after reading the question several times.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally possible in CSS using `@media`. Consider the following code ::

```
@media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    img { 
        /* do things */
    } 
}
```

See this article -> [Introduction to CSS Media Queries](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries.shtml)